# How to animate UITableView separators fading out?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I tried using the `UIView` `animateWithDuration` method, putting in `self.tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` in the animations block, but that doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is going to be to turn off separators on the table, add your own separator view to each cell, and animate the alpha of that separator view in each cell to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property, sepColor, and set its initial value in viewDidLoad,

```
self.sepColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
```

When you want to fade the separators, call this code,

```
-(void)fadeSeperators {
    static float alphaFloat = 1.00;
    UIColor *newSepColor = [self.sepColor colorWithAlphaComponent:alphaFloat];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = newSepColor;
    alphaFloat -= 0.05;
    if (! alphaFloat <.01) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeSeperators) withObject:nil afterDelay:.05];
    }
}
```